# gzip: stdin: not in gzip format Error i am getting

Tags: bash, ubuntu, cassandra, tar

I have installed apache-cassandra-3.11.13-bin.tar.gz under my ubuntu instances. When I am trying to run this command **tar xzvf apache-cassandra-3.11.13-bin.tar.gz**  it is throwing error like
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

I tried to check the file type by running **file apache-cassandra-3.11.13-bin.tar.gz**
it shows me
apache-cassandra-3.11.13-bin.tar.gz: HTML document, ASCII text, with very long line
Can anybody helped me how to extract this ?

Comment: Sounds like it's not a gz but an html page. `less` it and see. Also, _Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers._ There are other sites in the [SE network](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology) better suited for this kind of questions.

Comment: `apache-cassandra-3.11.13-bin.tar.gz` is a HTML file.